# Is there a way to disable some function in python class so that it cannot be used except using it in inside its class?

Tags: python, python-class, python-object

for example i have *myClassFile.py* file with code as follow:

```
class myClass:

    def first(self):
        return 'tea'

    def second(self):
        print(f'drink {self.first()}')
```

then i have *run.py* file with code as follow:

```
from myClassFile import myClass

class_ = myClass()
class_.second()
```

which when i run will output

```
>>> 'drink tea'
```

how to prevent someone to write below code on *run.py* file or outside *myClass* ?

```
class_.first()
```

so that if they used that method outside *myClass* class it will be an error or some sort

Comment: You can't. You *should* name the function `_first` to indicate that it's not part of the public interface, but there's really nothing you can do to *enforce* that decision.

Comment: We're all consenting adults in Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a level of protection around methods and attributes by prefixing them with `__`.

But you can't make them totally private (as far as I know), there's always a way around, as shown in example below.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__a = 1

    def __method(self):
        return 2


obj = MyClass()

# obj.__a  # raise an exception
# obj.__method() # raise an exception
print(dir(obj)) # you can see the method and attributes have been renamed !
print(obj._MyClass__a) # 1
print(obj._MyClass__method()) # 2
```

Comment: Also, double-underscore name-mangling really isn't an access modifier, it's sole purpose is to prevent *accidental* name collisions in subclasses. Idiomatically, one would use a single-underscore here -- privacy by *convention*

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga indeed that was not dunder methods / attributes. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Python does not have support for these. You can mark them private by prefixing them with `_`, or make it harder to call them by prefixing them with `__`.

These are called private methods. To make a private variable or a method in python, just prefix it with a `__`, so `def second(self)` turns into `def __second(self)`.

This also works for variables and functional programming variables!

```py
class Test:  
    def test(self):
        self.__test()
        
    def __test(self):  
        print('_test')
        
        
x = Test()
x.__test()
```

gives an error, but `x.test()` prints `_test` out successfully!

Note, this can still be run by using `x.__Test__test()`

Comment: It's important to realize this does not do anything to *prevent* the method from being used; it's a convention to indicate that it *should* not be used.

Comment: But this is just a convention. I twill not hold anyone back from calling it

Comment: Sorry I meant `__`, not `_`

Comment: @Berlm no, **that isn't private either** and won't prevent it from being called. Python *only* has privacy by convention

Comment: `x._Test__test()` will work just fine.

Comment: It does give me an error when running it

Comment: yes, that is completely right. I was talking in terms of directly calling it @chepner. Of course python doesnt support it, but in terms of calling it directly, you can prevent it by uising `__`

Comment: So? Most people would care that the function itself not be called, not that it simply not be called using any particular name.